# Background jitter with v-sync off in standalone build (high fps/300+ fps)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies, jitter

So the last 2 months I had been reworking my PlayerController to be rigidbody based for the sake of having more interactions with rigidbodies i.e. pushing objects. This went all pretty well, until I started testing my game in a standalone build. I immediately noticed strange jitter/stutter in the background (the player runs smooth) when v-sync is turned off (with v-sync is turned off my computer runs the game at 300fps+). At first I thought it had something to do with Cinemachine, I'm using CinemachineFreeLook, but to be honest as of now I'm unsure if Cinemachine is what's causing the jitter/stutter. Something worth noting is that the jitter/stutter is not constant, while the fps seems constant the jitter/stutter might go away for like 20 seconds and come back after. I have obviously done alot of research the past week and have been reading plenty of posts about FixedUpdate vs. Update, but unfortunately without any luck.

**I tried to add as much information as possible to this post to give a good understanding of my project, but first the stuff I already tried;**

- Changing the Fixed Timestep from 0,02 to 0,01. (This kind of works,
  but I would like to prevent changing the Fixed Timestep)
- Turning on interpolate/extrapolate. (Now there is jitter with both
  v-sync turned on and off)
- Changing the CinemachineBrain Update Method to FixedUpdate/LateUpdate
  instead of SmartUpdate.
- Deconstructing the scene and removing some heavy on performance stuff
  like Volumetric Lighting and Planar Reflections.
- Creating a really barebones PlayerController with only the code to
  move the player.
- Removing the library folder of my project. (Read this somewhere
  online, but no luck)
- Turning of my Xbox One controller, to make sure there is only one
  input in use.
- Swithed the building from Windowed Fullscreen to Exclusive
  Fullscreen.
- Turned off one monitor while testing.
- Move all my code to FixedUpdate.
- [Added these 3 scripts and changed the Script Execution Order](https://www.kinematicsoup.com/news/2016/8/9/rrypp5tkubynjwxhxjzd42s3o034o8)
  (Couldn't get this to work)
- Put the input logic in FixedUpdate.

**Below you can see both my movement scripts, one is part of my actual PlayerController, while the other was the one I wrote for the barebones Player.**

```
void FixedUpdate() {

    _isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(_groundChecker.position, GroundDistance, Ground, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);

    _inputs = Vector3.zero;
    _inputs.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    _inputs.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    _inputs.Normalize();

    if (_inputs != Vector3.zero)
        transform.forward = _inputs;
        _body.MovePosition(_body.position + _inputs * Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

*This is the script I wrote for the barebones player controller.*

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    if (pushControllerScr._pushBlocker) {
        input = Vector3.zero;
    } else {
        input = new Vector3(InputManager.MainHorizontal(), 0, InputManager.MainVertical());
    }
    RunAxis();
    inputDir = input.normalized;
    inputDir.Normalize();

    // Makes the player able to move, while not landing or being dead
    if (!landState && !climbManagerScr.isClimbing) {
        Move(inputDir, running);
    }
}

void Move(Vector3 inputDir, bool running) {
    if (inputDir != Vector3.zero) {
        float targetRotation = Mathf.Atan2(inputDir.x, inputDir.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cameraT.eulerAngles.y;

        transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetRotation, ref turnSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(turnSmoothTime));
    }

    float targetSpeed = ((running) ? runSpeed : movementSpeed) * inputDir.magnitude;
    stateInfoBaseLayer = _anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);

    if (stateInfoBaseLayer.IsTag("Climbing") || stateInfoBaseLayer.IsTag("Standing")) {
        currentSpeed = 0f;
    } else {
        currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentSpeed, targetSpeed, ref speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));
    }

    if (stateInfoBaseLayer.IsTag("AirIdle") && currentSpeed > walkSpeed) {
        currentSpeed = walkSpeed;
    }

    velocity = transform.forward * currentSpeed + Vector3.up * _rb.velocity.y;

    if (_capsuleCol.enabled) {
        _rb.MovePosition(_rb.position + velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

*This is what I actually use in my PlayerController Script*

Below you can see some footage of the jitter/stutter. It was quite hard to capture it, since using any recording software like OBS dropped the fps in my game to a point where the jitter/stutter was disappearing. Sorry for the phone recording, but this was honestly the only way.

[Footage of my game showcasing the jitter/stutter especially noticable around the yellow ship.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJdG3K_heNE&feature=emb_logo)

And finally here's an album with some relevant settings in the inspector. [Imgur Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdScu.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your recording, it looks as if the player is smooth and everything else.

From my experience 99% of the time means the jitter comes from the camera not being synced up correctly to the player.

It seems you have done the right things, and usually **combining** the following should work fine:

1. `CinemachineBrain` should update on `FixedUpdate`
2. Use interpolate/exrapolate on your player's Rigidbody (we chose extrapolate)
3. Apply forces/changes to physics objects solely in `FixedUpdate`

If you do **all 3 together**, this should work smoothly regardless of vsync, frame rate, fixed delta time, etc

Obviously your specific project might have something else that's messing it up; but I've seen this issue countless times and usually these combined steps should solve it.

Comment: Hi Ron, as far as I know I already apply those steps. The only thing I’m not doing as of now is using interpolate on my rigidbody, but this is because of unwanted behavior while pushing other rigidbodies or walking into walls.

Comment: When using physics on your main character and you have a camera that follows it, if you don't follow all 3 rules; you're going to get jitters. I *think* that the issue that you see with pushing other objects, is perhaps that you're using `MovePosition` instead of controlling the Rigidbody via velocity. But quite honestly I'm pretty sure you have to turn on interpolation on for it to work smoothly.

Comment: Gave turning on Interpolate another chance, but unfortunately without any luck. It actually also makes the jitter appear while v-sync is on. I have also read that it's better to use MovePosition and to never change the velocity by script.